# phpPgAdmin: "Identificação desabilitada por motivos de segurança"

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Ao instalar o **phpPgAdmin** no Linux, aparece a seguinte mensagem: **"Identificação desabilitada por motivos de segurança"**. O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver e estou compartilhando aqui a solução.

No diretório de instalação do **phpPgAdmin** (geralmente o caminho é: **/usr/share/phppgadmin/conf/config.inc.php**), abra o arquivo chamado **config.inc.php** e altere a seguinte linha:

**De:**

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = true;
```

**Para:**

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

Após feitas as alterações reinicie o servidor web.